# Worker error: undefine

Tags: solidity, remix

I'd written the solidity code in Remix and I pressed the compile button.

The code didn't compile - no green thick.

And I had this error:

Worker error: undefine

Answer (score 1):

This means you're not connected to the internet.

Yes, Remix may open in your browser. And you may even be able to write code in it.

But, your code won't compile.

So, get connected to the internet.